# cPanel on Azure VM?

Tags: linux, azure, centos, cpanel

Has anyone done this? I have managed to install it but I am new to this and do not know what to specify as the server hostname. Would this be the DNS name that azure provides? As I believe it cannot be the server IP address.

Answer (score 0):

> I have managed to install it but I am new to this and do not know what
>   to specify as the server hostname. Would this be the DNS name that
>   azure provides?

You are right, we use the DNS name of Azure public IP address as the hostname, like this:
[image]

```
[root@jasonvm home]#hostname jasoncpanel.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com
```

After install Cpanel completed, we will get information like this:

[image]

Follow that, we can login this VM with Cpanel:
[image]

**Note**:
In Azure, **we should reset root password first**, in this way, we can use root to login Cpanel.

```
[root@jasonvm home]# passwd
Changing password for user root.
New password: 
BAD PASSWORD: The password contains less than 1 uppercase letters
Retype new password: 
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are access it now, what I advice you to contact the WHM support or port your issue on WHM community for better assistance.

I would advise to check the firewall rule to allow the traffic on WHM port